# SpriteKit : Stop specific action by tag

Tags: sprite-kit

Is there any way to stop specific action by tag in Sprite-Kit ?

```
    [self stopActionByTag:kTagActionHeroFlapAnim]; //cocos2d
    [self stopActionByTag:kTagActionHeroHitAnim];
```

Like above Cocos2d calls, is there any way in Sprite-Kit ?

```
    SKAction *rep = [SKAction repeatActionForever:animAction]; //how to tag ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Action key to stop specific Action. You need to specify key.

```
        [sprite runAction:rep withKey:@"Move_fade_seq"];

        [sprite removeActionForKey:@"Scale_fade_seq"];
```

Comment: It's worth noting that runAction:withKey: will also automatically stop an already running action with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Your ability to stop an action depends on how you start it.

`runAction:` is fire-and-forget. You can't do anything to that specific action running on that specific node after that. (Though you can stop all actions the node is running by calling `removeAllActions`.)

If you want to refer to a specific action after you've started running it on a node, start it with `runAction:forKey:` instead. The string key you pass has a similar purpose to the integer tag from Cocos2d — it lets you identify the action while it runs so you can do things with it later.

To stop an action that you started with `runAction:forKey:`, call `removeActionForKey:`.

The [*SKNode Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) describes all the methods for starting, stopping, and managing actions running on nodes.

Comment: Remove is remove, so there will be no way to restart or continue running an action after removeAllActions: method is call.

Comment: @AndrewShmig So? The author didn't ask about restarting/pausing/resuming an action, and rickster's answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, the author either didn't ask about removing an action :)

Comment: stop and remove are the same thing in this context, cocos callls it stopAction and SK removeAction

Answer (score 0):

By tag - nope.

By name - nope.

Just by using refs to actions.

Comment: how to stop action through reference of SKAction? I see removeActionForKey in SKSprite...not getting how to use.

Comment: @iPhone_360, set speed property to 0.0

Comment: In Sprite Kit there's no function to remove an action by reference (the action pointer). Setting an action's speed to 0 will pause it, but it'll remain in memory and attached to the node. If you don't plan on resuming the action later on you have to remove it with removeActionForKey:

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I think in current context we can assume that pause == stop.