# Stopping Repeat Actions Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

Here is my code:

```
rotateClockWise = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-M_PI duration:skRand(0, 2.5)];

rotateClockWise = [SKAction repeatActionForever:rotateClockWise];
[asteroid1 runAction:rotateClockWise];
```

Is there a way to stop the rotateClockWise action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SpriteKit : Stop specific action by tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411554/spritekit-stop-specific-action-by-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give a Key to an action:

```
[asteroid1 runAction:rotateClockWise withKey:@"rotateClock"];
```

and after you can stop this action in this way:

```
[asteroid1 removeActionForKey:@"rotateClock"];
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift

```
asteroid1.runAction(action, withKey: "actionKey")
asteroid1.removeActionForKey("actionKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

also `[asteroid1 removeAllActions];` will work if that's the only action you're asteroid1 has.

> Ends and removes all actions from the node.

more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/removeAllActions)